# How to async load nodes with ant design treeselect?

Tags: asynchronous, promise, tree, antd

The component:
https://ant.design/components/tree-select/
There is no example with the `loadData` option.

```
async getChildren(node) {
    console.log(node);
    let r = $.get("/tree", {id: node.value})
    console.log(await r);  // request works
    return r;
}
```

With this code I just see the tree loading and nothing happens. Not an error, but the child nodes are not appended to the tree.

If I don't return a Promise, I get a huge error and a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example of loadData function:

```
 onLoadData = (treeNode) => {
    console.log('load data...');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const treeData = [...this.state.treeData];
        getNewTreeData(treeData, treeNode.props.eventKey, generateTreeNodes(treeNode), 2);
        this.setState({ treeData });
        resolve();
      }, 500);
    });
  }
```

You can find it [here](http://react-component.github.io/tree/examples/dynamic.html) with more in-deep examples

To make it clearer:

- TreeData is an Array of TreeNode
  [source](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/tree-select/interface.tsx#L48)
- antd tree select uses rc-tree because antd is built on top of [rc-components](http://react-component.github.io/badgeboard/) you can see the [source](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/tree-select/index.tsx#L2)
- For lazy load you need to manipulate the treeNode, what above snippet
  does is: everytime loaded new data it will be a treeNode object, and
  will call the onLoadData() callback where you provide the code what
  to do with that node. (the sample just append to the state's treeData
  variable]

Comment: Is that the same component? It doesn't look like ant design. And, While this example works, it creates TreeNode component, and I'm trying to use treeData alone

Comment: Ant design is built on top of rc-components.http://react-component.github.io/badgeboard/. they are mantained by the same guys.  antd is just a themed version of rc-component with some trimmed props

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/tree-select/index.tsx#L2 . the proof

Comment: for lazyLoad you need to manipulate the treeNode, yourself, treeData is just an array of treeNode https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/tree-select/interface.tsx#L48

Comment: And how the rendering looks (JSX)? Do I have to use async recursive rendering to create TreeNodes? Like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/5ym6rw3yn4 . As you can see renderTreeNodes() is a recursive function. I don't like this way, I prefer to add nodes to treeData

Comment: you can just add callback treeNode the state treeData. you will need recursion anyway to add nested children. I think the full example I provided is very clear...